# Como utilizar múltiplas fontes de repositórios com prioridade no NPM?

Tags: npm

Eu sei que é possível utilizar registros locais com o comando

```
npm config set registry <registry url>
```

Porém, pelo que eu entendi, esse comando altera o NPM para buscar **somente** nesse repositório.

Também dei uma lida sobre [`scoped packages`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope), mas, pelo que eu entendi, ele só utilizaria o meu repositório quando eu declarasse expressamente que aquele pacote esta no meu repositório e, caso não fosse encontrado, diria que não foi possível instalar. Só que o que eu queria fazer era tentar buscar no meu repositório local e, caso não fosse encontrado nele, buscar no repositório do NPM (https://registry.npmjs.org/).

Queria saber se é possível fazer um `npm install` com essa ordem de prioridade de onde ele vai buscar os pacotes?

Comment: Deixa de ser preguiçoso Felipe, hahahaha. #abraços

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Até o momento não é possível, segundo a documentação. Eu também li bastante a documentação em busca desta solução. Uma possível solução é utilizar o [Nexus](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-2-npm-packages) como repositório local NPM e configurar um proxy para o NPM público. Ele terá exatamente o comportamento que você deseja:

> ...buscar no meu repositório local e, caso não fosse encontrado nele,
>   buscar no repositório do NPM

Basicamente se o Nexus não localizar o pacote desejado em seu repositório local ele irá buscá-lo no NPM público e fará o cache local.

Outra referência sobre esta solução: https://medium.com/react-redux-best-practice/establishing-private-npm-repository-over-nexus-7a45d9f1cf0d